# Select the offset of a row respecting the order without fetching all previous rows

Tags: mysql, offset

First I want to make clear this is not a simple `LIMIT x,y` question. I want to know if it is possible to do a query like the following peuso query.

```
SELECT *, OFFSET_OF_ROW()
FROM `table` 
WHERE `some_column` = someValue 
ORDER BY `some_other_column`;
```

the pseudo function `OFFSET_OF_ROW()` should give the number of rows which would come before the selected row (+1) if there was no condition `` `some_column `` = someValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't particularly efficient, but it will do what you want:

```
select @rownum := 0;
select * from (
    select @rownum := @rownum + 1, id, some_column, sortcol
    from `table`
    order by `sortcol`
) all_rows 
where `some_column` = someValue;
```

Comment: but it's for sure more efficient than fetching all rows until i find the one i need and count the number of previous fetches.

Comment: I'm seeing even worse performance. I can't see any way to make it faster, it's a butt-ugly hack.

Comment: I tested this against fetching all rows until I find the proper one. It's way faster if the match is the first row and also 20-50% faster if the match is the last row! so i'll stick with that.

Comment: Thinking of rows as "ordered and numerable" in a table is not really appropriate for MySQL. If you want to say "this is the umpteenth row", it's best to have a column 'counter' which actually counts. Create the column, update the column once using this script, then use the column.